# Add GIT_CONFIG in CMake FetchContent_Declare fails on Linux

Tags: linux, cmake, azure-devops

I'm trying to set `http.extraheader` to get credentials into a Azure Devops pipeline, by setting `http.extraheader="AUTHORIZATION: bearer $ENV{System_AccessToken}"`. Consider the following snippet:

```
# For CI we need to set the AUTHORIZATION for git clones
if(DEFINED ENV{System_AccessToken})
  set(GIT_CONFIG_EXTRA_HEADER "AUTHORIZATION: bearer $ENV{System_AccessToken}" CACHE STRING "")
endif()

# Fetch the toolbox
include(FetchContent)
FetchContent_Declare(toolbox
  GIT_REPOSITORY https://repo/toolbox
  GIT_CONFIG http.extraheader=${GIT_CONFIG_EXTRA_HEADER}
)
```

This works on Windows, but on Linux I get the following error:

```
[1/9] Creating directories for 'toolbox-populate'
[1/9] Performing download step (git clone) for 'toolbox-populate'
Cloning into 'toolbox-src'...
error: key does not contain a section: AUTHORIZATION:
fatal: unable to write parameters to config file
```

So, in essence the string in `${GIT_CONFIG_EXTRA_HEADER}` is not quoted correctly I guess, but I cannot figure out what to do.

---

Looks like a bug in CMake. I filed an [issue](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/issues/20354).

Comment: Did you try to quote `${GIT_CONFIG_EXTRA_HEADER}`, e.g. `GIT_CONFIG http.extraheader="${GIT_CONFIG_EXTRA_HEADER}"`?

Comment: @Bodo same error on Linux and also fails on Windows with a CMake error: `Argument not separated from preceding token by whitespace.`